# Maven YUI Compressor Plugin Causing process-resources phase to not run?

Tags: maven, yui-compressor

I have a maven project that builds a war file.

Including the yui compressor in my maven build file is causing files, found in src/main/resources/ unrelated to any js files, processed during the process-resources to be empty when they are copied into the target directory.  Very weird, indeed.  Once the yuicompressor plugin is removed from the cycle, the other resources are processed just fine.

Anyone ever seen that (please, say yes ;-) )?

Here's my config:

The YUI Compressor config:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compress</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/extjs*/**/*.js</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/extjs*/**/*.css</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And the Resources config, containing the files that are empty when copied into the target dir:

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
              <include>**/*.properties</include>
              <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

To repeat:  the files (log4j.xml, etc) in the resources directory are being copied over to the target directory, but they are empty.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is the YUI Compressor plugin has the resources directory as one of the locations to include for compressing implicitly.  It was being run after the resources plugin executed, overwriting the xml and .properties files in the resources dir with empty files (because xml and .properties files don't contain javascript).  My fix was to add new excludes to the plugin's config:

```
  <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude> <!-- <-- this one here -->
                    <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude> <!-- <-- and this one -->
                    <exclude>**/extjs*/**/*.js</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/extjs*/**/*.css</exclude>
                </excludes>
```

This is still less than ideal, however, because any resources without an xml or .properties suffix will still be parsed by the yui compressor; I'm back to the original problem.

I tried this exclude, but it didn't work:

```
<exclude>**/resources/*.*</exclude>
```

does anyone have any idea why the above wouldn't work, or have an idea how to tell the yui plugin *not* to process anything in resources?